What halachic arguments do egalitarian movements use for egalitarianism?
How do movements like Hadar, Conservative Judaism, or any others make arguments for egalitarianism in Jewish life? Answers that include primary sources are appreciated

@AlBerko Questions about non-orthodox movements are allowed: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99226/why-does-the-reform-siddur-cut-out-most-of-krias-shema and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53123/what-is-the-reform-view-of-the-origin-of-the-torah and many others. https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/is-there-not-room-for-non-orthodox-opinions gives guidance that heterodox questions are allowed

@AlBerko as already pointed out, that is simply not true.

@AviAvraham Good to know! Since when?
